# setValue method in Nightwatch is not working

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js

I am trying to setup a new Nightwatch project for the purpose of automating a simple Google search page. My assert for *searchbox present on page* passes, but I am not able to perform any mouse/keyboard action on the elements (`Searchbox`, or `SearchButton`)

**Note:** I am running Nightwatch version `1.0`.

**Test case:**

```js
module.exports = {
  before : function(browser) {
   browser.globals.waitForConditionTimeout = 5000;
  },
    tags: ['google'],
    'Demo test Google' : function (browser) {
         browser 
         .url('http://www.google.com') // Go to a url
         .waitForElementVisible('body', 10000) // wait till page loads
         .pause(2000)
         .assert.title('Google') // Make sure Site title matches
         .assert.visible('input[name=q]') 
         .setValue('input[name=q]', 'nightwatchjs') // send values
         .click('button[name=btnG]') // click on search box
         .pause(1000)
         .end()
       },
};
```

I have also tried with this approach:

```js
var setValue =  function(sel, value) {
  $(sel).val(value).change();
};
```

```js
module.exports = {
  before : function(browser) {
       browser.globals.waitForConditionTimeout = 5000;
  },
    tags: ['google'],
    'Demo test Google' : function (browser) {
         browser 
         .url('http://www.google.com') // Go to a url
         .waitForElementVisible('body', 10000) // wait till page loads
         .pause(2000)
         .assert.title('Google') // Make sure Site title matches
         .assert.visible('input[name=q]') 
         .execute(setValue, ['input[name=q]', 'nightwatchjs'])
         .click('button[name=btnG]') // click on search box
         .pause(1000)
         .end()
       },
};
```

This is the output log:

## [Google] Test Suite

Running:  Demo test Google

- √ Element  was visible after 133 milliseconds.
- √ Testing if the page title equals "Google"  - 18 ms.
- √ Testing if element  is visible  - 61 ms.

**Error log:**

> Error while running .setElementValue() protocol action: unknown error:
>   call function result missing 'value'
>
> TimeoutError: An error occurred while running .setValue() command
>   on :    {"status":-1,
>       "state":"",
>        "value":
>         {"message":"unknown error: call function result missing 'value'",
>          "error":["  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.120)","  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120
>   (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.17763 x86_64)"]},"errorStatus":13,"error":"unknown error: call function result missing 'value'","httpStatusCode":200}
>          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)    NoSuchElementError: An error occurred while running .click() command
>   on :
>          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Comment: were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to click() on input first, and then use setValue(), sometimes it helps