# Cannot use setValue() in nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js

I am attempting to write a simple script in nightwatch.js that will open Google, and enter text into the search field. I am running into an issue using both `setValue()` methods to send text to the element.

Here is my script:

```
module.exports = {
  'Search bar displayed on Google Home Page'(driver) {

    driver
      .url('http://www.google.com')
      .assert.urlContains('google')
      .assert.title('Google')
      .waitForElementPresent('input[title="Search"]')
      .pause(5000)
      .setValue('input[title="Search"]', 'test123') // error happens here
      .end()
  },
}
```

When using `setValue()`, I am seeing the following error:

> Error while running .setElementValue() protocol action: TypeError [ERR_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS]: Error while trying to create HTTP request for "/wd/hub/session/ed0680ce58544facf2a4b193eccbc223/element/[object Object]/value": Request path contains unescaped characters
>       at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:115:13)
>       at Object.request (http.js:42:10)
>       at HttpRequest.createHttpRequest 
>       at new Promise ()
>       at Selenium2Protocol.sendProtocolAction

For some reason, `.setValue()` is trying to send `Object object` as the `WebElement` ID in the request URL.

The script successfully executes the `assert` and `.waitForElementPresent('input[title="Search"]')`, so I know that the element is on the page. I added a `pause(5000)` to ensure the page has sufficient time to load before attempting to send keys. I have also tried running `.click()` before `.keys()` to try and bring the element into focus.

I believe the syntax is correct but I am still new to nightwatch so that could be an issue as well.

This user has almost the exact same problem as me, but no answer: [setValue method in Nightwatch is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58437187/setvalue-method-in-nightwatch-is-not-working)

I am using `chromedriver` version `80.0.3987.16`

I am using `nightwatch` version `1.3.4`

I installed `chromedriver` through `npm` using `npm install chromedriver` and set the path to `chromedriver.exe` in my `nightwatch.json` file:

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["tests"],
  "output_folder" : "reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "page_objects_path" : "./page_objects",
  "globals_path" : "",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "./node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/selenium-server/3.141.5-server.jar",
    "log_path" : "./reports",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "./node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe",
      "webdriver.gecko.driver" : "",
      "webdriver.edge.driver" : ""
    }
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "path" : ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "marionette": true,
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    },

    "chrome" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone help me understand what the issue is here?

Comment: are you downloading chromedriver through npm or manually?

Comment: I installed chromedriver through npm -- `npm install -g chromedriver` and I set the path in `nightwatch.json` for `"webdriver.chrome.driver": "C:/Path/To/chromedriver.exe"`. I have edited my question to include my full `nightwatch.json` file.

Comment: I am not able to find that version in npm. I am not sure if installing it globally has any impact. I have project https://github.com/spnraju/nightwatchjs-selenium-example/blob/master/package.json#L32. I have added your test into it and it is working fine. I am checking with latest version of chromedriver.

Comment: Works with latest version (80.0.1) of chromedriver as well. Try uninstalling your current chromedriver and install the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for checking that against your own repo. I will check my environment variables and make sure there's no stray `chromedriver.exe` in my Path as well. Running `chromedriver -v` gives me the output `ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.16 (320f6526c1632ad4f205ebce69b99a062ed78647-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#185})`

Comment: Now I get it, even though the npm version is '80.0.1', the version of chromedriver binary inside that package is '80.0.3987.116'. I have added your test to my repo. You can try cloning that and see what happens. https://github.com/spnraju/nightwatchjs-selenium-example/pull/39

Comment: @Raju I uninstalled and re-installed chromedriver through `npm uninstall -g chromedriver` and `npm install -g chromedriver` and I am still seeing the issue. I cloned your repository and got everything running (i.e. chrome browser opens and navigates to google) but all subsequent lines failed after that, this time the complaint is with `getElementAttribute()`. This is certainly an issue with my machine configuration but after uninstalling / reinstalling chromedriver, I am stumped here.

Comment: I would advise not to install any of the dependencies globally unless they are really required.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by adding `"w3c": false` under `"chrome"` in my `nightwatch.json` file.

Special thanks to @Raju whose `nightwatch.conf.js` file in their sample repository had an example of this.

I changed this:

```
  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "path" : ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "marionette": true,
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    }
```

To this:

```
  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "path" : ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "marionette": true,
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true,
        "chromeOptions": {
            "w3c": false
        }
      }
    }
```

Adding the `chromeOptions` field plus `"w3c": false` has everything working as expected now.

Comment: _ChromeDriver_ / _Chrome_ is in transition from _OSS_ to _W3C_. `"w3c": false` isn't the ideal solution.

Comment: I would be happy for a better solution - this question still does not have an accepted answer. I'm still very new to nightwatch so I am unsure what the convention is. I see this issue documented in the release notes https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/releases/tag/v1.1.12 with chrome 75 but my issue is with chrome 80.